# DateTime data from XML convert to string

Tags: php, string, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date format using the DateTime function. The date data is taken from an external XML file, how can I convert the data intro a string in the DateTime function?

**Here's the code:**

```
echo "Date: " . $date = new DateTime((string)$info->channel[0]->item[0]->pubDate); echo $date->format("d-m-Y H:m") . "<br />";
```

**This is the error:**
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in

Something I'm forgetting?

Comment: This question is not clear at all, please explain your problem

Comment: I justed edited it, better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using string concantation with a datetime object. You need to convert the date to a string before trying to echo it:

```
$date = new DateTime((string)$info->channel[0]->item[0]->pubDate);
echo "Date: " .  $date->format("d-m-Y H:m") . "<br />";
```